# Efficient way to find "hook words" in a list of words?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

A hook word is a word that you can add one letter to the beginning or end of and make a new word.

I have a rather large list of words (around 170k), and I would like to select 5 random hook words.  The issue is that the method I am using is extremely slow.  See below:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var hookBases = (from aw in allWords  //allWords is a List<string>
                from aw2 in allWords
                where aw2.Contains(aw) 
                      && aw2.Length == aw.Length + 1 
                      && aw[0] == 'c'
                select aw).OrderBy(t => rnd.Next()).Take(5);
```

When I try to access anything from `hookBase` it spins for several minutes before I give up and kill it.

Can anyone see any obvious mistakes with how I am attempting to do this?  Any suggestions on a more efficient way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, allWords should be a `HashSet<string>`, not a `List<string>`, for efficient lookup.

Once that's done, iterate over the hashset, and check if removing the first or last letter gives a new valid word. That's your hook word.

```
HashSet<string> result = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (string word in allWords) {
    string candidate = word.Substring(0, word.Length - 1);
    if (allWords.Contains(candidate)) { result.Add(candidate); }
    candidate = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
    if (allWords.Contains(candidate)) { result.Add(candidate); }
}
```

If you want to do this with LINQ:

```
List<string> hookWords = allWords
    .Select(word => word.Substring(0, word.Length - 1))
    .Concat(allWords.Select(word => word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1)))
    .Distinct()
    .Where(candidate => allWords.Contains(candidate))
    .ToList();
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/qMSo5)

Comment: @AbeMiessler: I added a `Distinct` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Probably wouldn't want to be using LINQ with this one as there are so many items in the collection.  That overhead will add up and wouldn't be ideal.

Answer (score -1):

I have done a something similar recently. I tried with linq, storing a .net assembly with regular expressions in ddbb and stored procedures.
I found that the most efficient way was to use stored procedures. The transact engine have been highly optimized by Microsoft for this kind of operations.

Best regards